# Encapsulation and use of LINQ logic in functions using dot notation

Tags: c#, linq, variables, chaining

I tried my best to explain in the title, however I am trying to achieve giving linq statements an 'alias' and still use them in dot notation.  Allow me to explain further.

below we have a list that has a linq statement applied:

```
private List<string> _matches;

var output = _matches.Where(x => x.EntityScore == 100).ToList();
```

I agree that this is simple to read.  However I wish to simplify it further especially when the statements start to get bigger.  This is an example of linq getting longer than I care for:

```
private List<string> _matches;

var matchAddressList = _matches.Where(x => x.EntityDetails.Addresses.Any(x => x.Street.Equals(inputObject.Address)
                                                                           && x.StateProvinceDistrict.Equals(inputObject.State)
                                                                           && x.City.Equals(inputObject.City))).ToList();
```

What I am trying to do is alias certain groups of LINQ and then call that linq as a dot operator

for example:

```
var finalOutput = _matches.perfectMatches().addressMatches(inputObject).someOtherMatchCondition(inputObject)
```

I think the above line is clear and easily readable.  Future devs dont necessarily have to look into the logic. They can read the business domain name and understand what it does. 
I want to avoid the following line, as I believe the previous code is more clean:

```
var finalOutput = someOtherMatchCondition(addressMatches(perfectMatches(_matches)));
```

the previous line is how I feel you would go about it using functions at a basic level.  However I am struggling to find a way to create an alias or encapsulate the linq logic into a **business domain name** and then use that as a dot operator.

I have tried expression body definitions:

```
public List<string> perfectMatches => _matches.Where(x => x.EntityScore == 100).ToList();
```

is this going to require extensions of another class? or the writing of generics? or am I perhaps unaware of a standard way of doing this?

Comment: LINQ itself is composed of extension methods.  As Blechdose and Jason have commented, you need to implement your own extension method `PerfectMatches`.  You can look at the LINQ source itself at https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs - this may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: maybe this is helpfull too:
 [How to add custom methods for LINQ queries (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-add-custom-methods-for-linq-queries)

---

It has to be an extension method to make use of the dot notation.
Do you mean something like that. It is rather pseudo code than working. You may have to play around with the types or try out some kind of generic approach:

```
public class ProductionCode
{
    public void MyMain()
    {
        var myList = new List<EntityThingType>() { .... };

        var newList = myList.PerfectMatches().AddressMatches(myInputObject).ToList();
    }
}

public static class test
{
    public static IEnumerable<EntityThingType> PerfectMatches(this IEnumerable<EntityThingType> myList)
    {
        return myList.Where(x => x.EntityScore == 100);
    }


    public static IEnumerable<EntityThingType> AddressMatches(this IEnumerable<EntityThingType> myList, MyObjectType inputObject)
    {
        return myList.Where(x => x.EntityDetails.Addresses.Any(x => x.Street.Equals(inputObject.Address)
                                                                    && x.StateProvinceDistrict.Equals(inputObject.State)
                                                                    && x.City.Equals(inputObject.City)));
    }
}
```

Comment: So I did end up creating extensions based on what you show here.  I wasn't sure how to make it generic though.  What I mean is that my extension methods are for my particular business domain.  It would be great to be able to create these dot notation aliases without attaching it to any particular business domain.  However your post and the attached examples were extremely helpful.  Thank you!

Comment: @AJLocke check the link in the answer. i saw some generic linq extension examples there

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods). You can have the `perfectMatches()` method be an extension method that takes an `IEnumerable<string>` and return the same. Then you can chain those together.